# php URL encoding error

Tags: php

I have the following line in my code

```
$lib  = simplexml_load_file("http://www.goodreads.com/book/title.xml?key=MYAPIKEY&title=" . $current_book,null,true);
```

when this is sent, it is sent like this

```
http://www.goodreads.com/book/title.xml?key=MYAPIKEY&title=Dashing%2BThrough%2Bthe%2BSnow%2BMary%2BHiggins%2BClark%0A
```

When this happens, the book is not found and an error is returned . . .

However, if i type into my browser

```
http://www.goodreads.com/book/title.xml?key=MYAPIKEY&title=Dashing+Through+the+Snow+Mary+Higgins+Clark
```

Then i get a valid XML response, and i can use this to complete my code.

So, how do i send this without the + getting changed to %2B ?

And what is the %0A at the end of the URL?

Comment: Show us the whole url, without php variables. PS: `%2B` is a plus-char hex-encoded, you're performing the encoding twice, `%0A` is a new line character. "So, how do i send this without the + getting changed to %2B ?" --- don't perform premature encoding and it'll be fine

Comment: Storing the url in a variable and to replace the codes for characters not solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your url seems to be encoded twice.

Since you are not encoding at all in the code you show (by the way that would be the proper place to do that) it must have happened before.

The error is not in this code but somewhere before that.

You could correct it like this:

```
$lib  = simplexml_load_file("http://www.goodreads.com/book/title.xml?key=MYAPIKEY&title=" . trim(urldecode($current_book)),null,true);
```

However that is only a workaround for an existing error, you should fix the prior encoding.

Also the character you mention is a newline character, thats the reason for trim

Comment: Thank you.

I encoded the variable before using it

    $this->get_book_array(trim(urldecode($line)));

And left my original line as it was, it worked.

Thanks again